# Problema al obtener datos a través de ajax - framework7

Tags: javascript, framework7

[image: Texto]

La consulta ajax a un archivo php de hasta 150 registros funciona bien, cuando se realiza una consulta de 800 registros al obtener los datos y mostrarlos en el DIV, ocurre este problema de que demora unos casi 1.5seg para mostrar el html en el div.

[image: Texto]

código del route.js

```
{
    path: '/lazy-load/:Page',
    url: './pages/lazy-load.php',
    name:'productos',
    options: { transition: 'f7-dive', },
    on: {
        pageAfterIn: function (e, page) {
        },
        pageBeforeIn: function (e, page) {
        },
        pageInit: function (e, page) {
        
        var jsonData= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataUser"));
        //alert(jsonData.name);
        var referencia=this.id;
        var user = jsonData.id_usuario;
        var idBusiness = jsonData.idBusiness;
            
        var page_view   =   app.view.main.router.currentRoute.params.Page;
        app.request.post('/ajax-post/productos/productos.php', { categoria: page_view,user:user,idBusiness:idBusiness }, function (data) {
        $$('#div-productos').html(data);
        $$('.title').html(page_view);
        });
        
        $$('.page').addClass('page-lazy-load');

                                    },
        lazyLoad: function (el) {
                console.log(el);
            },
            lazyLoaded: function (el) {
                console.log(el);
            },
            lazyError: function (el) {
                console.log(el);
            },
      },
  },
```

Comment: No entiendo cual seria el problema. Por qué un retardo de 135ms a 870ms estaría mal si estas obteniendo 5 veces mas información?

Comment: Cuando carga la página de los 800 registros que menciono al mostrarlos, deja de funcionar las funciones añadidas en el pageInit, ejemplo: el lazy load, no cargan las imágenes, la creación del botón stepper no va.
es como si ninguna de las funciones adicionales no funcionasen al cargar más de los 150 registros que menciono.

Comment: Al días de hoy el navegador no tiene problema en almacenar en memoria 800 registros (yo lo he probado hasta con 20.000), el tema pasa por renderizar este contenido en pantalla. Y se incremente si cada registro son por ejemplo, crear 5 divs, un img, un h1 etc, cada nodo lo hace más lento. La técnica que se ocupa para solventar esto se llama `virtual scrolling`, con la cual solo creas lo elementos visibles y cuando bajas con el scroll se crean los otros

Comment: Revisare lo de `virtual scrolling` ya que de momento muestro toda la información de golpe.